# manage data to Array in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a few problem when I get all data from datatable jquery its not in array that I want.Below is my code,

```
var cells = [];
        var rows = $("#PtptnFileTblId_1").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
        for(var ii = 0; ii < rows.length;ii++)
        {   
            for(var i = 1; i < 15 ;i++){
              cells.push($(rows[ii]).find('td:eq('+ i +')').html());
            }
        }
        console.log(cells);
```

when I see the console log ,the data show like this :

```
["0000000000", "BP4", "99", "00987799201502", "SB1302BD2613", "911224126057", "Test1", "00791740", "zxa", "000000", "00000000", "null", "null", "10016020876162", "0000000000", "BP4", "59", "01678059201502", "MC1411BC8301", "940627146418", "Test2", "00672980", "qwq", "000000", "00000000", "null", "null", "12131023048090", "0000000000", "BP4", "13", "01482513201502", "SB1409BD7872", "910120126189", "Test3", "00672894", "AU", "000000", "00000000", "null", "null", "10016020934832"]
```

But the way I want is ,

```
[Array[15], Array[15], Array[15]
0:[Array[15]
    0:"0000000000"
    1:"BP4" 
    2:"99"
    3:"00987799201502" 
    4:"SB1302BD2613" 
    5:"12121312" 
    6:"TEST1" 
    7:"00791740"
    8:"zxa"
    9:"000000" 
    10:"00000000" 
    11:"null" 
    12:"null"
    13:"10016020876162"
2:[Array[15]
    0:"0000000000"
    1:"BP4" 
    2:"99"
    3:"00987799201502" 
    4:"SB1302BD2613" 
    5:"12121312" 
    6:"TEST1" 
    7:"00791740"
    8:"zxa"
    9:"000000" 
    10:"00000000" 
    11:"null" 
    12:"null"
    13:"10016020876162"
3:[Array[15]
    0:"0000000000"
    1:"BP4" 
    ......
```

Please anyone help me how I want to turn my code like the way I show above .This is my first time using jquery function like .push() .So is it any possible way.Any help will greatly appreciate.Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array.splice(0, 15)` will take 15 elements from the array each time.

```js
var arr = ["0000000000", "BP4", "99", "00987799201502", "SB1302BD2613", "911224126057", "Test1", "00791740", "zxa", "000000", "00000000", "null", "null", "10016020876162", "0000000000", "BP4", "59", "01678059201502", "MC1411BC8301", "940627146418", "Test2", "00672980", "qwq", "000000", "00000000", "null", "null", "12131023048090", "0000000000", "BP4", "13", "01482513201502", "SB1409BD7872", "910120126189", "Test3", "00672894", "AU", "000000", "00000000", "null", "null", "10016020934832"]

var result = [];

while(arr.length) {
    result.push(arr.splice(0,15));
}

console.log(result);
```